# Day of week is off by one by one day Android-times-square

Tags: android, calendar, dayofweek, android-time-square

We are facing an issue for the day off for the calendar by one day when the timezone is set to AUTO mode in Samsung S7. Even after the few hours calendar is showing the perfect dates with days.

For your reference, I am attaching the screenshot for the issue with device's calendar and selected timezone.

Note: we are using the following SDK

[Android-time-square lib](https://github.com/square/android-times-square)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just to check, are you sure you’ve got the right year? Your screen shot seems to agree with February *2018*.

Comment: @OleV.V. yes, we have counter checked this issue very first, when we are clicking on any date on that time we are printing the clicked date in Log files. Also, you can refer the following link for the more details regarding this issue. https://github.com/square/android-times-square/issues/269